# No local gulp install found

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

In reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284805/no-local-gulp-install-found-even-after-installing-npm-install-g-gulp#) I've run `sudo npm install gulp -g` and `npm install gulp --save-dev`, but no matter what I do I keep running into this error. Gulp does not see the local node_modules/.bin/gulp it seems and keeps complaining with the same error as mentioned above:

`No local gulp install found in` with the local path.

I've tried looking at permissions, uninstalled, re-installed, tried different versions, but no luck. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please add your system OS to narrow the issue.
What is the output of `npm ls`?

Comment: I am working on OS-X 10.8.5 and npm ls gives:

`ETSL@0.0.0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/sl-etsl-authorsuite/frontend
├─┬ bower@1.3.4
├── connect-livereload@0.4.0
├── connect-modrewrite@0.5.11
├─┬ gulp@3.4.0
├─┬ gulp-angular-templatecache@1.1.3
├─┬ gulp-assets@0.1.0
├─┬ gulp-autoprefixer@0.0.6
├─┬ gulp-clean@0.2.4
├─┬ gulp-concat@2.2.0
├─┬ gulp-connect@2.0.5
├─┬ gulp-filter@0.4.1
├─┬ gulp-html-replace@1.1.0
├─┬ gulp-imagemin@0.5.1
├─┬ gulp-jshint@1.6.2
├─┬ gulp-karma@0.0.4
├─┬ gulp-load-plugins@0.5.1
├─┬ gulp-ngmin@0.2.0
├─┬ gulp-svgmin@0.4.6
├─┬ gulp-uglify@0.2.1
...
└── require-dir@0.1.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that this was caused my a combination of factors. I am not sure exactly what the problem was, but npm cache was a big part of it. After clearing it, and re-installing node and npm, I was able to get past this hurdle.