# Installing gulp to windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, gulp

I've installed gulp

```
npm install --global gulp
```

and set envidoment variable:

```
 - variable: GULP_HOME
 - Value: C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp  (..\gulp is folder)
```

in environment variables
And try to run "gulp". Then i get a message in cmd:

```
C:\myaccount\workspace\todoparrot>gulp
[09:47:24] Local gulp not found in C:\myaccount\workspace\todoparrot
```

How to set gulp to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No local gulp install found even after installing npm install -g gulp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284805/no-local-gulp-install-found-even-after-installing-npm-install-g-gulp)

Comment: i did the same when i check gulp -v shows gulp command not found

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You must locally install gulp to that folder. Use the following command:

```
npm install gulp
```

if it is not fixed, try to install it globally:

```
npm install gulp-cli -g
```

Answer (score 6):

I installed gulp globally, then used the link command to link the current directory to the global installation. I used the command -

npm link gulp